# Angular's filter to check if object is empty null or undefined

Tags: angularjs, filter

I would like to have a filter that will check if a given json object is empty, null or undefined. Without using any third-party lib.

```
function isObjValid(obj) {
      return !(obj === undefined || obj === null || Object.keys(obj).length === 0)
  };
```

But when I tried to filter the object from my template :

```
<ng-if ng-if="$ctrl.data | filter:isObjValid">
   ...
</ng-if>
```

I get this error :

```
Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {}
```

Is there any way to avoid `notarray` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom filter

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('isValidObject', function(){
    return function(obj){
      return !(obj === undefined || obj === null || Object.keys(obj).length === 0);
    }
});
```

Use in view:

```
<div ng-if="$ctrl.data | isValidObject">
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/WTyhHnyLIHFWZDXa7cAv?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, I had already the correct logic. But your plunker really helped me understand how I should set my  filter in my template.

Answer (score -1):

As per the **[Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)**, you are allowed to use filters only for array of elements. In your case **data** seems to be just an object and not an array.

Suggesting you without a filter as in the below code

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

  <div ng-if="isObjValid(data)">
    Valid data
  </div>
  <div ng-if="!isObjValid(data)">
    In Valid data
  </div>
  <div ng-if="isObjValid(name)">
    Valid name object
  </div>
</body>
```

Your controller must be the following

```
var app = angular.module('demoModule', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.isObjValid=function(obj) {
      return !(obj === undefined || obj === null || Object.keys(obj).length === 0)
  };
});
```

Check out the **[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/xdD6j55FvdBn39QWvZrH)**

Comment: First statement is not correct. You can use custom filters to filter anything